# C# Word interop, как узнать число строк в ячейке?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, interop

C# Word interop, как узнать число строк в ячейке?
[image: Word]

Свойство

```
Cell.Range.Paragraphs.Count;
```

даёт результат 4, т.к. 4 абзаца.

Comment: Никак. В ворде нет такой единицы измерения "строка", так как их количество определяется только при рендере текста, точнее оно не определяется, вы просто когда видите текст - можете посчитать.

Comment: @aepot , жаль, спасибо